# Windows Compact Embedded: Calling C# DLL from C++

Tags: windows, interop, compact-framework, windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact

I am attempting to call a C# .NET DLL from an unmanaged C# application. I have tried writing a C++/CLI wrapper but was unable to compile for a CE target. After some digging through many form posts it is the general consensus that C++/CLI is not supported for WinCE however I have not found an official Windows document supporting that. I have also tried creating a COM wrapper for my DLL which compiles fine however fails to create an instance of the wrapped object at runtime. I have registered my COM component correctly but it seems that it is also not supported.

Does anyone know of:

1. Any workarounds to get C++/CLI or COM to work for WinCE 2013.
2. A preferred method of Inter-Process Communication between C++ and C# applications.

Comment: If all else fails you can use the [CLR Hosting API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/) that allows you to load and execute managed assemblies from unmanaged code.

Comment: Hosting doesn't exist in the compact framework

Answer (score 0):

There really are no workarounds since hosting doesn't exist.  You need to use IPC, and which is "best" really depends on your use case.  Memory-mapped files work well for data sharing, sockets or named events for commands.  Unlike the desktop, CE supports sending a simple 32-bit value with a named event as well (SetEventData IIRC?) which can be super lightweight and handy in some cases.

Comment: Do you know if Named Pipes or any Duplex Pipes are supported on WinCE?

Comment: Not supported, no.

Comment: Is there a way to create a pipe from scratch using CreateFile? Ex. `myProperty.txHandle = CreateFile(
   L"\\\\.\\pipe\\testPipe",
   GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
   FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
   NULL,
   OPEN_EXISTING,
   0,
   NULL);`

Comment: Named pipes aren't supported, so that's not going to work.